# Loop through an array and return the values sorted by a grouping pattern

Tags: php, arrays, string, grouping

I'm trying to loop through an array and return the values sorted by a pattern (groups of two). My abstract math skills are failing me. I'm stumped, I can't figure out the pattern. Here's what I have so far.

```
$ars = array(
    0 => "red",
    1 => "blue",
    2 => "green"
    3 => "yellow",
    4 => "purple"
    5 => "black",
    6 => "white",
    7 => "orange"
);
$group_1 = '';
$group_2 = '';
foreach ( $ars as $ar ) :
   if ($ar == 0 || $ar == 1 ) :
     $group_1 .= $ar;
  elseif ($ar == 2 || $ar == 3) :
    $group_2 .= $ar;
  elseif ($ar == 4 || $ar == 5) :
    $group_1 .= $ar
  elseif ($ar == 6 || $ar == 7) :
    $group_2 .= $ar;
  endif;
endforeach;
echo group_1; //result (red,blue,purple,black)
echo group_2; //result (green,yellow,white,orange)
```

Having trouble creating an efficient foreach statement that will sort through a variable number of $ars and return them in this grouping. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ars = array(
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green",
    "yellow",
    "purple",
    "black",
    "white",
    "orange"
);

$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($ars);$i++){
    if ($i%4>=2)$array2[] = $ars[$i];
    else $array1[] = $ars[$i];
}

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Oh sry, was too late. But perhaps it's better to sort the items into an array?

Comment: It's called modulo. Returns the rest of a division. 0/4 = 0, rest 0; 1/4 = 0, rest 1; 2/4 = 0, rest 2; 3/4 = 0, rest 3; 4/4 = 1, rest 0. In this case used for an infinite loop over an array that has a length divisible by 4. Writes the first two results of 4 into array1, the last 2 into array2.